# Rebuild actual FullCalendar eventClick Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar calendar where the click-events having sweet-alert 2 popups in the functions. The pop up boxes have multiple drop downs that are built using sweet-alert HTML functionality. Here's an example of the code,

```
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view, date) {
        var clickValue = calEvent.description;
        if (clickValue != 'OWEDVALUE') {
            var btn = "button";
            drop = drop.replace("select-style-purple", "select-style-green");
            options = options.replace("select-style-purple", "select-style-green");
            var title = calEvent.title.replace("\n", "<br />");
            swal({
                title: moment(calEvent.start).format("MM/DD/YYYY"),
                type: 'info',
                inputClass: 'select-style-green',
                inputValue: calEvent.teachNum,
                html: title + '<br />' +
                    'Notes: ' + calEvent.description + '<br /><br />Select A New Teacher: <br /><br />' + options + '<p></p>Select A New Service: <br /><br />' + drop + 
                    '<br /><br /><div style="border:2px solid green;" >Update Hours: ' +
                    '<input type="text" autofocus id="newHours" style="display:block !important;" class="sweet-alert-input"/>' +
                    '<input type="hidden" id="oldHours" value="' + calEvent.hours + '" /></div>' +
                    '<button type="' + btn + '" id="btnA" value="' + calEvent.id + '" style="background-color: #D46752 !important;" class="sweet-alert2-button">Delete Record</button> ' +
                    '<button type="' + btn + '" id="btnB" value="' + calEvent.id + '" class="sweet-alert2-button">Update Record</button> ' +
                    '<button type="' + btn + '" id="btnC" style="background-color: #B9B9B9 !important;" class="sweet-alert2-button">Cancel</button>',
                showConfirmButton: false
            });

            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        }
```

This is an example of one of the drop down boxes built in a javascript var.

```
options = '<select id="teacherDrop" class="select-style-green">';
for (var i = 0; i < record_array.length; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + record_array[i].teachNum + '" ';
    if (record_array[i].teachName == data[0].teacher)
       options = options + ' selected="selected" >' + record_array[i].teachName + 'TEST</option>';
    else
        options = options + '>' + record_array[i].teachName + 'TEST</option>';
}options += '</select>';
```

What I would like to do is to rebuild the drop downs(updating the selected value) after every click-event ajax call, so I need to rebuild the actual eventClick functions not the eventSources. I have tried multiple things to no avail.

Here is the function that gets called when one of the submit buttons gets pressed from the Sweet-Alert.

```
$(document).on('click', "#btnB", function () {
  if ($.isNumeric($("#newHours").val())) {

    var qString;
    qString = "id=" + this.value;
    qString += "&teacherId=" + $("#teacherDrop").val();
    qString += "&hours=" + $("#newHours").val();
    qString += "&service=" + $("#serviceDrop").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_data_ManageHomebound_Students.aspx?qt=updateStudentRecord",
        data: qString,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            swal.close();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', data[0].id);
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                title: "Service Type: " + data[0].serviceType + "\nTeacher: " + data[0].teacher + "\nHours: " + $("#newHours").val(),
                id: data[0].id,
                start: data[0].start,
                end: data[0].start,
                allDay: data[0].allDay,
                description: data[0].description,
                teacher: data[0].teacher,
                homeBoundPaidID: data[0].homeBoundPaidID,
                teachNum: data[0].teachNum,
                serviceType: data[0].serviceType,
                color: 'green',
                textColor: 'black'
            }, false);
            $('#ant').addClass('animated zoomInDown').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('animated zoomInDown');
            });

            //Here I'm going to rebuild the service type drop down and try to recreate all click events.
            var options;
            options = '<select id="teacherDrop" class="select-style-green">';
            for (var i = 0; i < record_array.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + record_array[i].teachNum + '" ';
                if (record_array[i].teachName == data[0].teacher)
                    options = options + ' selected="selected" >' + record_array[i].teachName + 'REBUILT</option>';
                else
                    options = options + '>' + record_array[i].teachName + 'REBUILT</option>';
            }
            options += '</select>';

            var temp = $("#hoursGiven").val();

            if ($("#newHours").val() >= $("#oldHours").val()) {
                  temp = parseFloat(temp) + (parseFloat($("#newHours").val()) - parseFloat($("#oldHours").val()));
            } else {
                temp = parseFloat(temp) - (parseFloat($("#oldHours").val()) - parseFloat($("#newHours").val()));
            }

            $("#hoursGiven").val("");
            $("#hoursGiven").val(temp);
            $("#hoursOwed").val(parseFloat($("#totHoursNeeded").val()) - parseFloat(temp))
        }
    });

  } else {
    sweetAlert({
        title: "Oops!",
        text: "Please Make Sure Pay Rate is Numeric. \nPlease fix form and try again.",
        type: "error"
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

So after the Ajax is successful I rebuild the options var that holds the drop down information for Sweet-Alert. This is the point where I need all of the click-events to be rebuilt to use the updated code(options var). The purpose of this is I'm trying to get the drop downs to have a pre-selected value of the most recently used item(teacher, etc...).

Comment: really not sure what you mean? what "click-event ajax call" are you referring to? I can't see one in the code. And you talk about changing the dropdown's selected value - presumably this depends on the data in the two arrays that you compare...but you don't say where that data comes from, or how/when it's updated from the server. Is that the ajax call you mentioned? If so, how is that linked to your eventClick method (at the moment, there seems to be no link between them at all).

Comment: ADyson I have edited the original question to try and better explain my issue. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: ok. I think you can just redefine the "eventClick" handler, in the manner demonstrated here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/handlers/

Comment: P.S. A couple of other points: 1) I would advise you strongly _not_ to use `async: false` in your ajax - it's well known to cause horrible user experience by locking up the browser during the request. If the request unexpectedly takes a longer than normal, users often think the page has crashed and close their browser. Also, Chrome (and maybe others) have already deprecated this setting, so you can expect it to be removed in a future release. 2) If you set `dataType: "json"` in your ajax settings, then the line `data = JSON.parse(data);` can be removed, because jQuery will do it automatically

Comment: ADyson, Thanks for the suggestions, however, I couldn't get this to work. I don't believe that the on/off feature actually redefines/rebuilts the handler it just adds to it. So, based on their example every time my Ajax call is successful it just adds a console printout to it. For example, the first time I get one print out, the second time two, and so on and so forth. After digging through their site I'm not sure that this type of functionality is available.

Comment: yes...you'd have to use "off" to remove the previous version each time, before running the "on" call. Sorry, I thought that would be clear. That's how JavaScript event handlers work in general.